# Count space character before a letter/number in a python pandas column

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas dataframe, which looks like this:

```
columnA columnB
A        10
 B       12
  C      13
  D      14
 010     17
```

How can i count the space characters before the first string/number/letter in the column A in a new column? So for example:

```
columnA columnB counter
A        10      0
 B       12      1
  C      13      2
  D      14      2
 010     17      1
```

Comment: Do you want only space (Unicode U+0020) or any kind of whitespace? In which case you can use `r'^(\s*)'` in place of `'^( *)'` in my answer.

Comment: In that concret issue I only had space

Comment: The method is generic, now you can adapt it to anything else if you want ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can combine [`str.extract`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.extract.html) and [`str.len`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.len.html):

```
df['counter'] = df['columnA'].str.extract('^( *)', expand=False).str.len()
```

Output (I added quotes around the string for visualization):

```
  columnA  columnB  counter
0     "A"       10        0
1    " B"       12        1
2   "  C"       13        2
3   "  D"       14        2
4  " 010"       17        1
```

Reproducible input:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'columnA': ['A', ' B', '  C', '  D', ' 010'],
                   'columnB': [10, 12, 13, 14, 17],
                   'counter': [0, 1, 2, 2, 1]})
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`str.findall`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.findall.html) then extract the len of the first item:

```
df['counter'] = df['columnA'].str.findall('^ *').str[0].str.len()
print(df)

# Output
  columnA  columnB  counter
0       A       10        0
1       B       12        1
2       C       13        2
3       D       14        2
4     010       17        1
```

Comment: Double `str` slicing is not optimal ;)

Answer (score 1):

You can use RegExp with `apply()`, why not:

```
import pandas as pd
import re

df = pd.DataFrame({'columnA': ['A', ' B', '  C', '  D', ' 010'], 'columnB': [10, 12, 13, 14, 17]})

pattern = r'^\s*'

def count_spaces(s):
    return len(re.match(pattern, s).group())

df['counter'] = df['columnA'].apply(count_spaces)

print(df)
```

Output:

```
  columnA  columnB  counter
0       A       10        0
1       B       12        1
2       C       13        2
3       D       14        2
4     010       17        1
```

Comment: `apply` is slow: `reg = re.compile(r'^\s*') ; df2['count'] = [len(reg.match(s).group()) for s in df2['columnA']]` would be much more efficient ;)

Comment: @mozway sure, but we don't know OPs background and project. sometimes having several readable apply functions is much more profitable than the bunch of oneliners. my job is to propose)